# Can I expose an annotation property?

Tags: java, json, spring, annotations

If I declare an annotation class like so:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ReportType {

    public String reportName();
}
```

And then I build a List of a bunch of classes who use this annotation and supply a 'reportName' but apparently the property reportName is not exposed like a normal getter. I can access it in Java but if I return the List using spring there is no properties in the JSON string that gets translated from it. I was hoping to see:

```
{"reportName":"TPS Report"}
```

instead I see:

```
{}
```

Is there something extra I can do to get the reportName property to get included in the json?

Comment: Can you explain with a little code example what the thing is that you try to serialize? Sticking `@JsonProperty` works for most things, maybe for yours too?

Comment: That up there is exactly what I am trying to serialize - instances of classes which utilize that custom @ReportType attribute. Goal is to get the reportName to be serialized in JSON. I'm thinking I'm going to have to write a wrapper class around it which exposes getters in order to make it work.

Comment: Yes, one way is to have code like https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerAdapter.java#L36 in a parent class of all serialized classes that exposes the value as regular property. No need for setters. The other alternative would be a customer serializer for `Object` http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization but I imagine that gets difficult. Lastly, since you are in spring, I could imagine that you can somehow create dynamic proxy (sub)classes that expose the property regularly without having to inherit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of achieving this is to keep a field, reportName, in your POJO. Fill that field using the annotation value on class before passing the instance for JSON serialization.

```
@ReportType(reportName = "html")
public class HTMLReport {

    //Can be potentially moved to parent class of all reports.
    @JsonProperty("reportName")
    private String reportName;

    public String getReportName() {
        return reportName;
    }

    public void setReportName(String reportName) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }

}

public class ReportName {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        HTMLReport r = new HTMLReport();

        ReportType type = r.getClass().getAnnotation(ReportType.class);
        String reportName = type.reportName();
        r.setReportName(reportName);

        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
        m.writeValue(System.out, r); //Produces {"reportName":"html"}
    }

}
```